# What does flush command do?

Tags: php

What do you mean by

"I would do it after you've sent everything to the client and flushed it."

ThankinG you

Comment: It does the same that happens when you do *that other flush*. The buffer is the potty and it collects all you *output* to it. And when you are done, you flush it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/flush

> Flushes the write buffers of PHP and
>   whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a
>   web server, etc).

Answer (score 10):

Flushing is the operation involved when there is buffering over streams of data.

Let's assume a normal **stdout** stream. Printing every byte as soon as it arrives would be inefficient, that's why output is usually buffered and 'flushed' out in chunks. This reduces the overhead of doing this kinds of operations.

So what that sentence means is that he would do it just when data has been prepared to be sent and already effectively sent by flushing the buffer out.

Usually this operation is transparent to the developer, you can force a flush but you don't explicitly need to do it.

Comment: So what it does is..it collects all my data to be sent at once and then sends it to my client at once ?

Comment: If you are talking about a webpage what happens is that when php code is interpreted, the HTML output is first stored in a buffer and then flushed out to the client when it's all ready.. so basically yes, with flushing bytes are stored and then sent at once (or also many times but not for every single byte produced).

Comment: So how do i flush my content or fuse the flush tags..Php.net is difficult to understand !!

Comment: they pointed you to the PHP manual, I think you should give a look there to understand :)

Answer (score 3):

flush prints out any buffered output to the client.
everything you print out first goes into a buffer. 
you can also turn on explicit buffering if you want, so that nothing gets to the client but you can store it in the buffer for post editing of a website or something.
flush ensures that everything in the buffer is sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

[flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

> Flush the output buffer

So in my read it means when you delivered the webpage to clients' browser.

Answer (score 0):

This can mean a couple of different things, depending on the context. I'm assuming you mean flushing an outbut buffer.

An output buffer is where output is stored temporarily before being sent to a client all at once. Flushing means to send the stored data to the client. See the docs for [ob_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).